# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm posting here because i can't find anyone with this error. I'm using Rails 4.0.2 and when i try to save my form (it uses a collection_check_box) it gives me this message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/projeto_controller.rb:34:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/projeto_controller.rb:33:in `create'
```

I'm a little lost here because i don't have any attributes named `name`.
Here my controllers and models.

```
class Projeto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :usuario
  has_many :projeto_temas
  has_many :temas, through: :projeto_temas

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :temas

  validates_presence_of :titulo, :orgao_financiador, :periodo_inicio, :periodo_fim
end

class ProjetoController < ApplicationController

  # GET /projeto/new
  def new
    @projeto = Projeto.new
    render :layout => 'application_cadastro'
  end

  # POST /projeto
  # POST /projeto.json
  def create
    @projeto = Projeto.new(projeto_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @projeto.save
        format.html { redirect_to @projeto, notice: 'Projeto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @projeto }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @projeto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projeto/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projeto/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @projeto.update(projeto_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @projeto, notice: 'Projeto was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @projeto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end    
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_projeto
      @projeto = Projeto.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def projeto_params
      params.require(:projeto).permit(:titulo, :usuario_id, :orgao_financiador, :periodo_inicio, :periodo_fim, :resumo, :temas_ids => [])
    end
end
```

And the `Temas` model.

```
class Temas < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relacionamento_temas_pai, class_name: RelacaoTemas, foreign_key: :temas_pai_id
  belongs_to :relacionamento_temas_filho, class_name: RelacaoTemas, foreign_key: :temas_filho_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projeto

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :relacionamento_temas_pai

  validates :nome, presence: true
end
```

The part of the view with the ckeck_box

```
<div class="presquisadores-preview-action">
            <div class="temas-projetos-checkbox">
              <%= f.collection_check_boxes :temas_ids, Temas.all, :id, :nome %>
            </div>
          </div>
```

It has one attribute with the name `nome` which is portuguese for name, so it shouldn't affect anything.

Thanks in advance for the help, in really lost, and don't know what to do.

**--EDIT**

So... after a lot of research i didn't find the problem. Actually i was looking into some rails documentation and saw some issues with that version of the `activerecord` so i updated to rails 4.2.0 and the problem is now gone. 
I still don't know what caused it, but now my form saves normally.
Thanks for all the help folks

Comment: Without reading all of your code, `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass on save` means you did `something.name`.  Did you mean to do `something.nome`?  Go to line 34 projeto_controller.rb and check your spelling.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html   it's helping you to override default params

Comment: @m8ss i did a search in the project and didn't find anything with `.name`, i even removed all the gems and let just the standard to see if one of them is causing this error.

Comment: @IgorIvancha i didn't understand... sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Rails 4.0.2. I faced the same issue and when I updated to Rails 4.0.13 (the last in the 4.0.x series), the issue resolved itself.

From the github issues, I can only glean that this is because of some database bugs that Rails did not prepare for.